# Python: with open(filename, 'w') for a file that does not exist

Tags: python, file, text, file-io, fopen

## Background

I'm trying to write a script that creates a new LaTeX-file from a template I've made and
I've run into a bit of a snag when it comes to using the following code:

```
with open(filename + '.tex', 'w'):
    # Do stuff to filename.tex
    ...
```

Consider the above as **Option A**.

Here `filename.tex`, `filename` is a variable, (probably) doesn't exist within the directory from which the script is executed by the user. In **Option A** the file isn't created
by the `with open(...)` statement. I obviously need to create `filename.tex` in this context.

There is another way to open files, which is to be considered as **Option B**:

```
f = open(filename.tex, 'w+')
```

In the above statement the file is created if it does not exist.

Hence, my question:
Which of these options should I use if I mean to write
clear, well written code, that adheres to the shared view
of the Python community? *(Pythonic)*

If **Option A**,
I'd appreciate directions as to how to `touch` the file if it does not
already exist, a link would be splendid. (Or include in the answer)

Comment: _"In Option A the file isn't created by the `with open(...)` statement."_ Strange, it gets created on my machine.

Comment: @Kevin That is most peculiar indeed. I'll try a reboot!

Comment: @Kevin Now it works, suddenly (after a reboot).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open with both `w`, `w+` mode creates a file unless it exist. (truncates the file if it exist)

Difference between `w` and `w+` is:

- `w`: write only
- `w+`: read + write

Comment: In addition to that, if you really want to test the existence call  the function with no mode parameters and it will fail if the file does not exist. I don't know of any Pythonic convention about it but is the recommended way to test the existence of a file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82831/how-do-i-check-if-a-file-exists-using-python